# I am trying to navigate to another page on a checkbox selection of "yes". And I get error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

```
NavigateCheckbox .js
export default class NavigateCheckbox extends Component {
  state = { selectedOption: "" };

  handleOptionChange = e => {
    if (e.target.checked && e.target.value === "yes") {
      this.props.history.push("/newpage");
    }
    this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    const { history } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="radio">
          <label>
            <input
              type="checkbox"
              value="yes"
              checked={selectedOption === "yes"}
              onChange={this.handleOptionChange}
            />
            Go to new page
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

MainPage.js
import NavigateCheckbox  from "./NavigateCheckbox";
const MainPage= (props) => {
 return (
    <section className="screenshots">
    <NavigateCheckbox />
);
```

};
[enter image description here][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/47NAj.png
```

I am trying to navigate to another page on a checkbox selection of "yes". And I get error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

change class export to

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
...
class NavigateCheckbox extends Component {
    //..... code
}

export default withRouter(NavigateCheckbox)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not redirect to `newPage` as your routing seems to be incorrect. Check that proper routes are set. and whenever you need to redirect through `props.history`, you must export component with `WithRouter(your component name)`